# Time complexity plotting of binary search LOG base problem.

Tags: algorithms, logarithms, asymptotics

I'm given the problem: For x amount of elements, plot the time complexity (Big-O) of binary search vs linear search. What I don't understand is what base the time complexity of binary search should be. Given that log base 10 and 2 give different graphs for any x. I know that base doesn't matter for Big-O notation. But what do I need to consider when plotting this graph when determining time complexity advantage of binary search compared to linear search?

It matters I think because let's say we have 20,000 elements in our array. Then linear search takes 20,000 operations. But should it be for binary search $20,000\div\log_2(20,000)\approx1399 $ faster or $20,000\div\log_{10}(20,000)\approx 4650$ times faster?

Comment: You're right that for Big-O, the base of the log doesn't matter. To really answer this, you need to consider your goal. I think the goal is to plot the maximum number of times the array must be probed before the search concludes. If this is correct, maybe this more concrete version of the problem will help. It might be helpful to work out this value (the maximum number of probes needed) for some smaller arrays first to see what you need to do.